# UWP App stops receiving UDP Multicast messages

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, udp, hololens

I am currently running into a very strange problem. I am developping an application for Microsoft HoloLens with Unity 2017.4.2f2. The problem is that my code works well, but the HoloLens just won't receive any more UDP messages from my python server after few runs of my app.

Here is the code for the DatagramSocket connection :

```
private HostName inetAddr;
private DatagramSocket sock;
private int inetPort;
private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
private byte[] buffer;

private async Task ConnectSocket()
{
    sock = new DatagramSocket();
    sock.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;
    sock.Control.MulticastOnly = true;
    sock.Control.InboundBufferSizeInBytes = BUFFER_SIZE;
    await sock.BindServiceNameAsync(inetPort.ToString());
    sock.JoinMulticastGroup(inetAddr);
    // Send empty message to initialize communication
    await SendWithExistingSocket("");
}

private async Task SendWithExistingSocket(string text)
{
    if (sock != null)
    {
        Stream stream = (await sock.GetOutputStreamAsync(inetAddr, inetPort.ToString())).AsStreamForWrite();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(text);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}

private async void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    using (Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead(BUFFER_SIZE))
    {
        await streamIn.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(inetAddr.RawName);
    IPEndPoint from = new IPEndPoint(address, int.Parse(sender.Information.LocalPort));
    //Custom function for dealing with packet
    HandlePacket(buffer, from);
}
```

As I said, this problem is very strange because this code actually works, until HoloLens just stop receiving UDP Datagrams **(function Socket_MessageReceived not called)**. In my example inetAddr = 224.3.0.5 and inetPort = 7667

What is important to add, is that my app restarts receiving UDP messages **after a reboot of the HoloLens from the device portal**.

I don't have this problem when I'm deploying my UWP app on my local machine. Only when I'm deploying my app to the HoloLens. I also have an implementation of this communication with UdpClient class (for testing in the editor), which works very well and doesn't behave like this.

What I already tried :

- Checking whatever capability that is necessary (Internet Client & Server, Private Network Client & Server)
- Changing Multicast Address / Listening Port
- Checking network with WireShark (messages from the server are correctly sent)
- Calling socket.Dispose() when quitting the application

Any ideas why ?
Thank You

Comment: By consulting with my team, we're afraid you may met a compiler issue. Please try to bring down the unity compiler version to `Unity 2017.2.0f3` and tested it again. If worked, we will give a explanation for why to  your issue as the reply.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I reproduced the error by running my app like 15 times with Unity 2017.4.2f2 until no more messages are received. Then I tried to recompile the project with Unity 2017.2.0f3 and rerun the app, unfortunately, it didn't change a thing. UDP messages are not received and a reboot is still necessary

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Using` with your writer and receiver because that will kill the communication with your listeners. I had that problem, and it was driving me crazy until I do that. Now it works like a charm.

I receive the packages like this:

```
bool refresh = false;
bool sound = false;
string response;
uint stringLength = args.GetDataReader().UnconsumedBufferLength;
response = args.GetDataReader().ReadString(stringLength);
```

and write the packages like this:

```
IOutputStream outputStream;
HostName remoteHostname = new HostName("224.3.0.5");

outputStream = await socketinstance.GetOutputStreamAsync(remoteHostname, ClientPortNumber);

DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
writer.WriteString(request);
await writer.StoreAsync();
```